# New function in .click after first function has been completed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>

<div id="example">
 Content
</div>
```

Clicking `#link` triggers `.hide()` for `#example`
Now I want `#link` to trigger `.show()` for `#example`
I know this is very basic but I can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$('#link').click(function() {
   $('#example').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$('a#link').click(function() {
   $('#example').toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2NSx/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#link").click(function(){$("#example").toggle()});
```